# Complete set of commuting observables for an electron in a periodic potential (crystal)

Tags: operators, solid-state-physics, commutator, crystals, observables

In the case of an electron in a crystal,
lets say that $\hat{T}(a_1)$, $\hat{T}(a_2)$ and $\hat{T}(a_3)$ are the traslation operators.

We know that $[\hat{H}, \hat{T}(a_i)] = 0$, is this a complete set of commuting observables? (or operator, since I don't know if the traslation operator can be called an observable...)

In other words, we know that for one electron in a periodic potential the wave function can be written as:
$$\psi(\mathbf{r}) = e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}} u_k(\mathbf{r})$$
do $\mathbf{k}$ and $E$ (the energy) fully determine the wave function?

Comment: If by $E$ you mean the band index, then the answer is yes, up to the spin quantum number.

Comment: @MengCheng I mean the eigenvalue of $\hat{H}$. I'm sorry if the question is not clear but I have recently started the topic and I am having a hard time understanding the concepts.

Comment: I understand that $E$ is the energy. The most important feature of electron in a periodic lattice is that the spectrum generally forms bands. Namely, the eigenstates are labeled by $\mathbf{k}$ and a band index $n$. This band index is basically the same as the energy $E$. So I guess the answer to your question is yes, although usually we talk about bands more.